# Get user claims in a class asp.vnext beta4

Tags: c#, asp.net, claims-based-identity, asp.net-core-mvc

In the asp.net vnext, I am getting the user claims in the Controller using the following code:

```
 var claimsIdentity = User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
        var c = claimsIdentity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name);
        var temp = c.Value.ToString();
```

but using the same, I could not get it in my class (which used to store in DB).  I am getting the following error (in User) as

```
The name 'User' does not exist in the current context
```

I tried Thread.CurrentPrincipal without success. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

typically you would get access to User from the current HttpContext.

your class can declare a dependency on Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.IHttpContextAccessor in its constructor to get one passed in by dependency injection.
Then you can get it like this:

```
ClaimsPrincipal user = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User;
```

Comment: So I have to declare this httpcontextAccessor in both Controller as well as in my class.. right ?...  If i use the FromServices in my class as follows it gives error "Object reference not set..."  Code :   [FromServices]
       public IHttpContextAccessor _accessor { get; set; }

Comment: your controller already has access to HttpContext so you do not need to add a dependency on IHttpContextAccessor to your controller. I suggest make it a constructor dependency not get it from service locator, I have not tried using it from service locator, but in my code it works from constructor injection